# How to set an element to the value of a variable using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a portfolio website. The user can click through my work using left and right arrows. The left and right arrows set the variable x to 1,2, or 3 and sends it through a function "workSelection". As the user clicks through the work I want it to update work title to match the variable of the selected work (1,2 or 3).

```
var workTitle1 = "Work 1";
var workTitle2 = "Work 2";
var workTitle3 = "Work 3";

function workSelection(x)
{
      var loop = 1;
      while (loop < 4)
        {
          if (x == loop)
            {
                $("#workTitle").html('workTitle'+loop);
            }
          loop++;
        }
}
```

How can I change  $("#workTitle").html(**'workTitle'+loop**); to display the value of workTitle1, workTitle2, workTitle3. Instead now it is only showing a string with value of "workTitle1", etc... not the value of the variable itself.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: There are many values in the loop. I have shortened this for the question so you understand my point. The loop calls the values of about 7 different elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `window['workTitle'+ loop]`

```
var workTitle1 = "Work 1";
var workTitle2 = "Work 2";
var workTitle3 = "Work 3";

function workSelection(x)
{
    $("#workTitle").html(window['workTitle'+ x]);
}
```

**EDIT:**
There is no need to loop, I just answered the question how to change `$("#workTitle").html('workTitle'+loop)` to display the value of `workTitle1` :)

Comment: What's the point of the `while` loop to get one element out of it?

Comment: window['workTitle'+ loop] worked perfectly. Thank you! I have minimized my code in the example I showed you. The real code is bigger and the loop is necessary. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is more complicated than it needs to be. If you change the multiple strings to all be stored in an array you can retrieve them directly by index, instead of looping through them all. Try this:

```
var workTitles = [ "Work 1", "Work 2", "Work 3" ];

function workSelection(x) {
    $("#workTitle").html(workTitles[x-1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easier method

```
var workTitle = [];
workTitle[0] = "Work 1";
workTitle[1] = "Work 2";
workTitle[2] = "Work 3";

function workSelection(x)
{
      var loop = 0;
      while (loop < 3)
        {
          if (x == loop)
            {
                $("#workTitle").html(workTitle[loop]);
            }
          loop++;
        }
}
```

Comment: Note that `x` was apparently 1-based but you're using it against a 0-based `loop` value.

Comment: Corrected the first error. And logic can be improvised I guess.

Comment: loop is completely useless in the above scenario, Why not simple `$("#workTitle").html(workTitle[x -1]);`

Comment: That logic is a separate concern.

Answer (score 0):

This is where you want an *array* rather than individual variables. While it's *possible* with JavaScript to use individual variables (with `eval`, which you should avoid, or by making them globals and using the fact they become properties of `window`), there's no good reason to.

Here's the array version. Note that indexes start at 0:

```
var workTitles = [
    "Work 1",
    "Work 2",
    "Work 3"
];
function workSelection(x) {
    for (var loop = 0; loop < workTitles.length; ++loop) {
        if (x == loop + 1) { // Note the comparison, since `x` appears to be 1-based
            $("#workTitle").html(workTitles[loop]);
        }
        loop++;
    }
}
```

I don't see any need for the loop, though:

```
var workTitles = [
    "Work 1",
    "Work 2",
    "Work 3"
];

function workSelection(x)
{
    $("#workTitle").html(workTitles[x - 1]);
}
```

Comment: I don't know why this got -1, it is the best answer. There is no need for a loop.

Comment: @Guillaume: Well, I just found not one, not two, but *three* editing errors I made in it. :-) (Fixed now.) So fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

use an array

```
var workTitles = ["Work 1","Work 2","Work 3"];

function workSelection(x)
{
  $("#workTitle").html(workTitles[x]);


}
```

Comment: What's the point of the `while` loop to get one element out of it?

Comment: I ask myself the same question. But that's what he wanted

Comment: He never said he wanted the loop, only to get the right value.

Comment: then, I've removed the loop